# Is there a C++ MinMax Heap implementation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, heap

I'm looking for algorithms like ones in the stl (`push_heap`, `pop_heap`, `make_heap`) except with the ability to pop both the minimum and maximum value efficiently. AKA double ended priority queue. As described [here](http://www.diku.dk/forskning/performance-engineering/Jesper/heaplab/heapsurvey_html/node11.html).

Any clean implementation of a double ended priority queue would also be of interest as an alternative, however this question is mainly about a MinMax Heap implementation.

My google-fu has not been fruitful, but surely, it must exist?

Comment: How about: `std::priority_queue<T, std::deque<T>, C>`?

Comment: @Dirk - I thought std::priority_queue only guaranteed its first element to be the greatest. Are there any guarantees about the last one as well?

Comment: @Manuel: I was replying to the "Any clean implementation of a double ended priority queue [...]" part of the post.

Comment: @Dirk - *is* your suggestion a double-ended priority queue? - It looks to me like a single-ended priority queue that just happens to be stored in an std::deque rather than an std::vector or array or whatever.

Comment: I've been faced to this problem and I found a solution:
http://forestofcode.blogspot.com/2010/12/c-min-max-heap-implementation.html This is an implementation of a double ended priority queue using a MINMAX heap. I've not read all the answers, so your problem might be already solved. bests, Attila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the algorithm implementation try searching [Github](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=minmaxheap&s=stars&type=Repositories).

Comment: The hyperlink is broken, making this answer is obsolete.

Comment: @AmeyaVS Got it. Updated to GH search.

Answer (score 7):

Is there a reason you can't use `std::set`? It sounds like that, along with some wrappers to access and remove `set::begin()` and `--set::end()` will solve the problem. I imagine it will be difficult to find something that can generally do a MinMax Heap much faster than the default implementation of set.

Comment: Using std::set like you suggest is a workaround. It may be fine, but the MinMax heap would be the optimal solution for my problem, which is why I am asking for it specifically. But it's useful to keep in mind that std::set does more or less the same thing, so thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Perhaps lack of a unique key ? The keys in a set it is sorted by must be unique but not in a priority queue or double ended priority queue.

Comment: But nonetheless: This answer was very useful since I was never aware that the elements in a set or map are SORTED! I was believing that set and map were simply unsorted associative containers which only guarantee the uniqueness of keys but nothing more.

Comment: @Slauma There's also `std::multiset`.

Comment: Yeah, `multiset` sounds like it'd do what you need

Comment: But for large heaps / lots of operations the set implementation will be slower than a minimax heap... a minimax heap has the same time complexity as a normal heap, i.e. has O(1) find-min / find-max operations whereas for a general set implementation find-min and find-max are typically O(log n).

Comment: @antti: If you overload insert you can cache max/min element after insert, and thus have O(log n) insert but O(1) get max/min.

Comment: I've upvoted antti.huimas comment, but it could be premature optimisation. Abstract the queue, maybe, so that the implementation can be swapped out if genuinely needed. Or don't - the refactoring to swap it out if needed probably won't be much anyway. Also, I believe that finding the end-points in std::set is actually O(1) anyway - that the set object actually holds pointers to the min and max nodes as well as the root, so that begin() and end() are handled efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find any good implementations, but since no one else can either I'm guessing you'll be writing your own, in which case I have a few handy references for you.

A paper that no one seems to have mentioned is the original proposition for Min-Max-Heaps:

http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/mike/Papers/MinMaxHeaps/MinMaxHeaps.pdf

I've implemented a min-max heap from this paper twice (not in C) and found it fairly trivial.

An improvement, which I haven't ever implemented, is a Min-Max-Fine-Heap. I can't find any good papers or references on a plain old fine heap, but I did find one on the min-max-fine-heap, which apparently performs better:

http://arxiv.org/ftp/cs/papers/0007/0007043.pdf

Comment: I actually found a different (and improved) approach to my problem that didn't require a MinMax Heap. I just put a bounty on the question hoping something useful would come out of this. I already found that paper you link by the way, but it's a good thing you added it here for reference.

Comment: +1 for the first document which is well written with some useful psuedocode.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but here is a MinMax Heap i created back in my university days. This was part of a larger project so, there is an extraneous reference on a 'Stopwatch' class which measured performance. I'm not including this class as it isn't my work. It isn't hard to strip it out so i'm leaving the reference to it as it is.

The code on [snipplr](http://snipplr.com/view/28687/minmax-heap/)

To use, just create a new instance of the heap with whatever type you want to use. (Note, custom types would need to overload comparison operators). Create array of that type and then pass it to the constructor and specify the current array size and what the maximum should be. This implementation works on top of a passed array only since this is the only thing i needed, but you have everything you need to implement push and pop methods.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for lengthy code but it works fine except it may complicate to read and may contain some unnecessary variables and I am not uploading the Insert function. Use it as include .h
file.

```
#include <math.h>
#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0
#define Left(i) (2 * (i))
#define Right(i) (2 * (i) + 1)
#define Parent(i) ((i) / 2)

void TrickleDown(int* A, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++)
    {

        if (isMinLevel(i, n) == true)
            TrickleDownMin(A, i, n);
        else
            TrickleDownMax(A, i, n);
        Print(A, n);
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
    }
}

int isMinLevel(int i, int n)//i is on min level or not
{
    int h = 2;
    if (i == 1)
        return true;
    while (true)
    {
        if (i >= pow(2, h) && i <= pow(2, h + 1) - 1)
            return true;
        else if (i > n || i < pow(2, h))
            return false;
        h += 2;
    }
}

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    *a ^= *b;
    *b ^= *a;
    *a ^= *b;
}

void TrickleDownMin(int* A, int i, int n)
{
    int m, lc, rc, mc, lclc, lcrc, mlc, rclc, rcrc, mrc;
    int child;
    lc = Left(i);
    if (lc > n) // A[i] has no children
        return;
    else
    {
        rc = Right(i);
        mc = rc > n ? lc : (A[lc] > A[rc]) ? rc : lc;
        child = true; // keep tracking m comes from children or grandchildren
        // m = smallest of children and grand children
        lclc = Left(lc);
        if (lclc <= n)
        {
            lcrc = Right(lc);
            mlc = lcrc > n ? lclc :(A[lclc] > A[lcrc]) ? lcrc : lclc;
            mc = mlc > mc ? mc : mlc;
            if (mc == mlc)
                child = false;
        }
        rclc = Left(rc);
        if (rclc <= n)
        {
            rcrc = Right(rc);
            mrc = rcrc > n ? rclc : (A[rclc] > A[rcrc]) ? rcrc : rclc;
            mc = mrc > mc ? mc : mrc;
            if (mc == mrc)
                child = false;
        }
        m = mc;
        if (!child)//m is one of the child of i
        {
            if (A[m] < A[i])
            {
                swap(&A[m], &A[i]);
                if (A[m] > A[Parent(m)])
                    swap(&A[m], &A[Parent(m)]);
                TrickleDownMin(A, i, m);
            }
        }
        else    //m is child of i
        {
            if (A[m] < A[i])
                swap(&A[i], &A[m]);
        }

    }
}

void TrickleDownMax(int* A, int i, int n)
{
    int m, lc, rc, mc, lclc, lcrc, mlc, rclc, rcrc, mrc;
    int child;
    lc = Left(i);
    if (lc > n)//A[i] has no children
        return;
    else
    {
        rc = Right(i);
        mc = rc > n ? lc : (A[lc] < A[rc]) ? rc : lc;
        child = true; //keep tracking m comes from choldren or grandchildren
        //m = greatest of children and grand children
        lclc = Left(lc);
        if (lclc <= n)
        {
            lcrc = Right(lc);
            mlc = lcrc < n ? lclc : (A[lclc] < A[lcrc]) ? lcrc : lclc;
            mc = mlc < mc ? mc : mlc;
            if (mc == mlc)
                child = false;
        }
        rclc = Left(rc);
        if (rclc <= n)
        {
            rcrc = Right(rc);
            mrc = rcrc < n ? rclc : (A[rclc] < A[rcrc]) ? rcrc : rclc;
            mc = mrc < mc ? mc : mrc;
            if (mc == mrc)
                child = false;
        }
        m = mc;
        if (!child)//m is one of the child of i
        {
            if (A[m] > A[i])
            {
                swap(&A[m], &A[i]);
                if (A[m] < A[Parent(m)])
                    swap(&A[m], &A[Parent(m)]);
                TrickleDownMax(A, i, m);
            }
        }
        else      //m is child of i
        {
            if (A[m] > A[i])
                swap(&A[i], &A[m]);
        }

    }
}

void Print(int* a, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ", a[i]);
    }

}

int DeleteMin(int* A, int n)
{
    int min_index = 1;
    int min = A[1];
    swap(&A[min_index], &A[n]);
    n--;
    TrickleDown(A, n);
    return min;
}

int DeleteMax(int* A, int n)
{
    int max_index, max;
    max_index = n < 3 ? 2 : (A[2] > A[3]) ? 2 : 3;
    max = A[max_index];
    swap(&A[max_index], &A[n]);
    n--;
    TrickleDown(A, n);
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, have to -1 this. The first 3 `#define` lines alone are undefined behavior (why are you redefining `bool`, `true`, and `false`?), the following lines are bad style (use functions), and you rewrote swap for no reason (that's an incorrect implementation, by the way; consider when `a == b`). Good for providing an implementation, but I personally don't think a bad implementation is better than none.