# MinMax Heap Algorithm Implementation

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, heap

I searching **minmax heap** algorithm implementation,
i remember some things about this structure, her implementation is on one heap.
Even levels (floors) in heap tree is a min colored, and rest of nodes is max colored.
I remember some draft of workings of this but i searching some good document about it or some `C` or `C++` code snippet, i can't find any useful information's by Google, i think is a non widespread algorithm.

Greetings and Thanks for helpful answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a C++ MinMax Heap implementation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252793/is-there-a-c-minmax-heap-implementation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a little search on google and find this:

- http://www.coldbrains.com/code/code/C++/Data_Structures/Min-Max_Heap/MinMaxHeap.C.html
- http://www.coldbrains.com/code/code/C++/Data_Structures/Min-Max_Heap/MinMaxHeap.H.html

Comment: Site not available anymore as of Jan 28, 2013.

Comment: @slacy, you are right, but this answer just says simple google search can do this, and there is no need to ask it here.

Answer (score 7):

This is the original proposal for MinMaxHeaps:

http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/mike/Papers/MinMaxHeaps/MinMaxHeaps.pdf

I've implemented a heap off this and found it to be very simple. An improvement which I've personally never implemented is a min max fine heap:

http://arxiv.org/ftp/cs/papers/0007/0007043.pdf