# How to keep a large priority queue with the most relevant items?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

In an optimization problem I keep in a queue a lot of candidate solutions which I examine according to their *priority*.

Each time I handle one candidate, it is removed form the queue but it produces several new candidates making the number of cadidates to grow exponentially. To handle this I assign a *relevancy* to each candidate, whenever a candidate is added to the queue, if there is no more space avaliable, I replace (if appropiate) the least *relevant* candidate currently in the queue with the new one.

In order to do this efficiently I keep a large (fixed size) array with the candidates and two linked indirect binary heaps: one handles the candidates in decreasing priority order, and the other in ascending relevancy.

This is efficient enough for my purposes and the supplementary space needed is about 4 ints/candidate which is also reasonable. However it is complicated to code, and it doesn't seem optimal.

My question is if you know of a more adequate data structure or of a more *natural* way to perform this task without losing efficiency.

Comment: What about not inserting the X least relevant/prior candidates? As with an exponential growth those wouldn't be accessed anyway. You might want to variate X based on the size of the queue to allow the queue to get initial data. But still, your queue will fill, is there a stop condition?

Comment: @TomWij You don't know they are the least relevant until you find some candidates that are worse. In the problems tha I'm interested there are ussualy no stop conditions

Comment: When I generate a new candidate I compute a value based on a simple easily computable property which I think will generate more probably a good solution. So the relevancy is an heuristic used to prefer _a priory_ some candidates (and their offspring) over others, I'm not sure of how to call it.

Comment: Does relevancy matter only for candidates of equal or less priority?

Comment: No it doesn't, relevancy and priority are independent.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an efficient solution that doesn't change the time or space complexity over a normal heap:

In a min-heap, every node is less than both its children. In a max-heap, every node is greater than its children. Let's alternate between a min and max property for each level making it: every odd row is less than its children and its grandchildren, and the inverse for even rows. Then finding the smallest node is the same as usual, and finding the largest node requires that we look at the children of the root and take the largest. Bubbling nodes (for insertion) becomes a bit tricker, but it's still the same O(logN) complexity.

Keeping track of capacity and popping the smallest (least relevant) node is the easy part.

EDIT: This appears to be a standard min-max heap! See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180123174018/http://www.diku.dk:80/forskning/performance-engineering/Jesper/heaplab/heapsurvey_html/node11.html) for a description. There's a C implementation: [header](https://www.hugedomains.com/domain_profile.cfm?d=coldbrains&e=com), [source](https://www.hugedomains.com/domain_profile.cfm?d=coldbrains&e=com) and [example](https://www.hugedomains.com/domain_profile.cfm?d=coldbrains&e=com). Here's an example graph:

[image]
<sub>(source: [chonbuk.ac.kr](http://internet512.chonbuk.ac.kr/datastructure/heap/img/heap8.jpg))</sub>

Comment: @marcog +1 Haven't learned that at university, pretty interesting.

Comment: @Esteban http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252793/is-there-a-c-minmax-heap-implementation

Comment: @TomWij Oh, so I guess there's a standard data-structure :) /me looks to see how it compares to my idea.

Comment: Your solution seems valid when the priority and the relevancy are the same quantity and I discard the items with least priority, but I'm not sure how to use it when they are different quantities.

Comment: @Esteban Oh, I thought they were the same? Damn. This won't work then, and I don't think you can do any better than your current solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

"Optimal" is hard to judge (near impossible) without profiling.

Sometimes a 'dumb' algorithm can be the fastest because intel CPUs are incredibly fast at dumb array scans on contiguous blocks of memory especially if the loop and the data can fit on-chip.  By contrast, jumping around following pointers in a larger block of memory that doesn't fit on-chip can be tens or hundreds or times slower.

You may also have the issues when you try to parallelize your code if the 'clever' data structure introduces locking thus preventing multiple threads from progressing simultaneously.

I'd recommend profiling both your current, the min-max approach and a simple array scan (no linked lists = less memory) to see which performs best.  Odd as it may seem, I have seen 'clever' algorithms with linked lists beaten by simple array scans in practice often because the simpler approach uses less memory, has a tighter loop and benefits more from CPU optimizations.  You also potentially avoid memory allocations and garbage collection issues with a fixed size array holding the candidates.

One option you might want to consider whatever the solution is to prune less frequently and remove more elements each time.  For example, removing 100 elements on each prune operation means you only need to prune 100th of the time.  That may allow a more asymmetric approach to adding and removing elements.

But overall, just bear in mind that the computer-science approach to optimization isn't always the practical approach to the highest performance on today and tomorrow's hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I agree with you in your considerations. In this case however, I'm handling a very large array, which makes the scan impractical. The binary heap is very efficient data structure both theoretically and practically and I hoped some variation might be used in my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [skip-lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) instead of heaps you'll have O(1) time for dequeuing elements while still doing searches in O(logn).
On the other hand a skip list is harder to implement and uses more space than a binary heap.