# Finding max element in min heap

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, stl, heap

I have a min heap:

```
std::vector<int> h;
...
std::make_heap(h.begin(), h.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

The min heap operations `std::push_heap` and `std::pop_heap` are what I need for most cases but under very rare circumstances I need to find the maximum element in the min heap. I can do it with `std::max_element`:

```
std::max_element(h.begin(), h.end());
```

However, this must scan all the heap elements.

Does the standard library offer a more efficient algorithm for finding the max element in a min heap?

Comment: Related (and likely duplicate) https://stackoverflow.com/q/22703549/1870232

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** In a *min-heap*, the *maximum element* is in a ***leaf node***<sup>X</sup>. Therefore, you can restrict your search to roughly half of the elements of the heap, i.e., by limiting your search of the maximum element to the leaf nodes only:

```
auto max_it = std::max_element(first_leaf_it, h.end());
```

Note that this still takes linear time, but the constant factor is lower, roughly a half, than scanning through all the elements.

---

The following is an STL-like algorithm implementation for finding the maximum element in a min-heap provided by an iterator pair:

```
template<typename RandomIt>
auto min_heap_max_element(RandomIt first, RandomIt last) {
   auto n = last - first;

   if (n < 2)
      return first;

   auto first_leaf_it = first + (n - 2) / 2 + 1;
   return std::max_element(first_leaf_it, last);
}
```

To use it with your example:

```
auto max_it = min_heap_max_element(h.begin(), h.end());
```

---

#### How to find the *first leaf node* in a heap

The last element of the heap – the one pointed by `h.end()` – is clearly a *leaf node*, and its parent is the *last non-leaf node* because if there were a non-leaf node following this one, the element that we assumed to be the last element of the heap wouldn't be the last element, which is a contradiction.

Therefore, the *first leaf node* will be the element immediately following the last node's parent.

You can easily find out where's the parent node of the last node: Given *i* the index of a heap element, its parent is at index *(i - 1) / 2* . So, the index of the last non-leaf node is `(h.size() - 2) / 2` and the index of the first leaf node is therefore `(h.size() - 2) / 2 + 1`.

---

<sup>X</sup> Let's assume that the *maximum element* in a *min-heap* is located in a *non-leaf node* instead. This would imply that it has, at least, a child node. Due to the [*min-heap property*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), this child node has to be greater than or equal to its parent. If the child is greater than its parent – which is the maximum element – the child node is greater than the maximum. This is not possible because we have a contradiction. So, all its children nodes have to be maximums as well, and so on for these children as well. So, eventually, there is a maximum located in one of the leaf nodes if the maximum value is repeated in the heap or the only maximum value must correspond to a leaf node.

Comment: Thank you much for the explanation! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you really need better (i.e. sub-linear) time complexity, then consider using a [Min-max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap). Any node in this tree obeys the following property:

When a value is on an **even** level, then it is the *greatest* among its descendants.
When a value is on an **odd** level, then it is the *least* among its descendants.

The root thus has the smallest value, and one of its two children has the greatest value.

The time complexities of the insert/extract operations are the same as for a min heap.

Check [Is there a C++ MinMax Heap implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252793/is-there-a-c-minmax-heap-implementation)

Comment: Thank you I did not know min-max heap.